# Generating multple rows from one row

Tags: powerbi

I have a datasource in powerbi with the following format:

```
Sale#   Date        Value     Installments
1       Jan/2020    150,00    2 
2       Mar/2020    210,00    3
```

Then Installments column is the number of payments the sale will be divide. I need to transform the above datasource in one line for each payment, So if the first one has two installments, the payment will be divided in two months:

```
Sale#  Date       Value    
1      Jan/2020   75,00
1      Feb/2020   75,00
2      Mar/2020   70,00
2      Apr/2020   70,00
2      May/2020   70,00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in **Power Query** following these below steps-

**Step-1:** Add a custom column to your table as shown below-

[image]

This will generate a list per row.

**Step-2:** Expand the list as shown below (right click on the New column)-

[image]

You have now data as below-

[image]

**Step-3** Add a custom column as shown in the below image for incremental date-

[image]

**Step-4** Add another custom column as shown in the below image for equal installment amount-

[image]

**Step-5** You will have this below data now. Just remove **Yellow** marked columns and you will get your final desired output.

[image]